# Should I update README.md when I adding new features to open source project?

Tags: github, pull-request

I add a new feature to an open source project in Github that have no CONTRIBUTING.md. Should I explain my feature in README.md or I have to wait untill my pull request accept by Maintenance ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PR could very well include the README amended with your new feature.

If it does not, and the PR has not yet been review, it is not too late to add one more commit to your feature branch and push it: the associate PR will be updated.